# LibreOffice UNO Java - Edit MSWORD - Move Line position(to right)

Tags: java, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I am trying to edit a MS word document programatically with libreoffice UNO java api and convert to it to pdf. It works fine. but the Line format seems to have gone wrong. I opened the docx in LibreOffice GUI. I see it as [image: Anchor shifted to left]

If I right click - Postion and Size -> Horizontal from left to 1.0 it gets corrected. I am not sure how I do it using UNO java APIs.